# React: Calling Third-Party API (Behance) using Ajax

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am trying to use Behance API to get list projects, based on the keyword typed in my Search bar, however.. I keep getting this error after submitting an input on my search bar:

`BeSearchContainer.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined`

My onSubmit function:

```
 // triggered whenever the user submits the Search form
    onSubmitQuery(e) {
     e.preventDefault()
     let component = this
 // my error is from this next line..
      queryBehance(this.state.query).done( data => { 
       component.setState({
       query: '',
       hasSearched: !component.state.hasSearched,
       projects: data,
     })
   })
  }
```

My $.ajax function:

```
import $ from 'jquery'

 export function queryBehance(query) {
 var term = query.replace(/\s/, "+"); 
 var url = "https://www.behance.net/v2/projects?
 client_id={client_id}&field=" + term;

    return
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "get",
      data: {projects: {}},
      dataType: "jsonp",
    }).done((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      return response["projects"]
    }).fail(() => {
      console.log("Ajax request fails")
    })
   };
```

Do I need to adjust my Ajax method or is it a syntax error on my `onSubmitQuery` function? Please pardon my lack of knowledge as I am very new with React :) Any advise would much appreciated!

Comment: Is the request being sent correctly? How are you importing `queryBehance`?

Comment: Hi @RossAllen this is the import code:
`import {queryBehance} from './BeUtils' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is written exactly as you pasted in the question, then your `queryBehance` function is suffering from an [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/) after the `return` keyword. Move `$.ajax` to the same line as `return`:

```
import $ from 'jquery'

 export function queryBehance(query) {
 var term = query.replace(/\s/, "+"); 
 var url = "https://www.behance.net/v2/projects?
 client_id={client_id}&field=" + term;

    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "get",
      data: {projects: {}},
      dataType: "jsonp",
    }).done((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      return response["projects"]
    }).fail(() => {
      console.log("Ajax request fails")
    })
   };
```